# Why is std::make_tuple(7 + N...) legal in C++11?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, compile-time-constant

The following code is legal in C++11.

```
template<int... N>
std::tuple<decltype(N)...> f()
{
    return std::make_tuple(7 + N...); 
}
```

What does it mean?

Comment: How do you know it's legal? If you fed it to a compiler and it didn't complain, it means just about nothing.

Comment: Just to clarify: `+` has higher precedence than `...`, so this is the same as `make_tuple( (7 + N) ... )`.

Comment: This code is not legal in C++11. This is C++14 code due to the missing trailing return type.

Comment: @n.m. gcc uses this technique a lot to implement `std::integer_sequence`

Comment: "gcc uses this technique a lot". This tells **nothing** about legality of the code.

Comment: I removed the offending C++14, which doesn't add anything meaningful anyway.

Comment: @n.m., I just believe in gcc blindly.

Comment: @Potatoswatter now there is no compilable code in the question, bad edit IMHO...

Comment: That's a tad overly optimistic, and worth a mention in the question itself, just in case.

Comment: There, made it C++11.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

First of all, look at the template parameters: `template <int ... N>`. Even though a variable number of template arguments can be given to `f`, all of them must be of type `int`.

Now when you use `f<t1, t2, ..., tn>`, the [parameter unpacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template) `(7 + N...)` will follow the *pattern* `7 + N` and expand to

```
7 + t1, 7 + t2, 7 + t3, ..., 7 + tn
```

Therefore you end up with a tuple which contains each of your template arguments increased by seven. The details can be found in section 14.5.3 Variadic templates [temp.variadic].

> 3. A pack expansion consists of a pattern and an ellipsis, the instantiation of which produces zero or more instantiations of the pattern in a list [...].

Comment: [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/239fe332227e245b). Note the `-std=c++1y`.

Comment: @rubenvb: Noticed it beforehand, but didn't think about the automatic type deduction that much (too much Haskell lately). But now that I think about it, is it actually possible to create a function with the same template parameters and type in C++11 without sacrificing kittens?

Comment: @rubenvb: I see myself out. I knew there was something like `decltype`, but I haven't used templates meta programming in ages. Two hours of sleep isn't enough anymore :D.